# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, date, cakephp-3.0

I am using the following query, but when it is running then getting mysql syntax error. I am using cakephp 3 framework. Error is generating -`>where([DATE('Bookings.created') => date("Y-m-d")])`  for this condition, so can you suggest how can avoid this issue.

```
$this->loadModel('ServiceManager.Bookings');
            $queryTodayAppointment = $this->Bookings->find('all')
                ->select(['Users.fullname', 'Bookings.slot_time'])
                ->where([DATE('Bookings.created') => date("Y-m-d")])
                ->contain(['Users'])
                ->order(['Bookings.id' => 'DESC'])
                ->limit(5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you actually have to use the DATE function there are many ways to implements this.

simplest one (that's what you were already trying to do but you simply forgot to quote the function)

```
->where(["DATE(Bookings.created)" => date("Y-m-d")])
```

But you could also use cake SQL functions ([reference](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions))

```
$query = $this->Bookings->find();
$date = $query->func()->date(['Bookings.created' => 'identifier']);
$query->select(['Users.fullname', 'Bookings.slot_time'])
    ->where(function ($exp, $q) use($date) {
        return $exp->eq($date, date("Y-m-d"));
    })
    ->contain(['Users'])
    ->order(['Bookings.id' => 'DESC'])
    ->limit(5);
```

Comment: by using this ->where(["DATE('Bookings.created')" => date("Y-m-d")]) , SQL is running, but i am not getting data. For more information, created field type is DateTime. so I am wanting those data which has been created today.

Comment: sorry, there was a typo. I forgot to remove the single quotes. I'm going to edit

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to user the DATE() function here. Just compare the data with the current date:

```
->where(['Bookings.created' => date("Y-m-d")])
```

Comment: They are not equivalent.  `DATE()` strips any time component in `Bookings.created`.

Comment: My bad, forgot it was DATETIME.